# With Underscorejs, how to find whether an array contains another array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have this

```
var matches = bookmarks.filter(function(x) {
    return _.contains(x.get("tags"), 'apple');
});
```

Which will return the bookmark objects that have the apple tags

I want to put an array there instead to pull and all the bookmarks that have the matching values, similar to this

```
var matches = bookmarks.filter(function(x) {
    return _.contains(x.get("tags"), ['apple','orange']);
});
```

This doesn't work, any way to get it to work?

EDIT: Im sorry, bookmarks is a collection and im trying to return the models that have the apple and orange tags

Comment: Unrelated... why are you mixing underscore and native array processing methods? `Array.filter` and `_.contains`. Shouldn't you use `_.filter`?

Comment: @JosephSilber Ahh, I didn't know about `_()`, I haven't actually used underscore yet though

Comment: Title makes no sense to me

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**If tags is a string, your code it would be**

```
return _.indexOf(x.get("tags"), ['apple','orange']) > -1;
```

Example with indexOf : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H9LHX/)

**If tags is an array, you can use intersection**

```
return _.intersection(['apple','orange'], x.get("tags")).length > 0;
```

Example with intersection: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRxtW/)

Comment: Hi please take a look at the edit, I forgot some details. Sorry.

Comment: Yes tags is an array and im trying to return the objects that has the values from that array

Comment: i think you could just `return _.intersection(['apple','orange'], x.get("tags")).length` no need to test for `> 0`

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be a function for that in underscore. However, you can easily combine other functions to accomplish this:

```
_.mixin({
  containsAny: function(arr, values) {
    // at least one (.some) of the values should be in the array (.contains)
    return _.some(values, function(value) {
      return _.contains(arr, value);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi please take a look at the edit, I forgot some details. Sorry.